# Email is already in database, returns as if it isn't

Tags: php, mysqli, registration

Here is some background information on what I'm trying to do here. I'm try to create a registration form for my website (successful so far until this point). Data can be entered into the DB. The only thing I'm trying to do now is prevent duplicate email/usernames from being entered into the db. Through much stackoverflow research, I have found and tested the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM users WHERE email = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    return $stmt->num_rows;
}
```

What I then do is following:

```
if(user_exists($user_email) > 0) {
    echo "Email already exists!";
}
```

But is passes by this if statement as if the email does exist in the database!
The email I'm trying to enter, for my tests is `testemail@testemailweb.com` which is already in the database! Would someone possibly point out where I have messed up in my code? Is there a silly mistake that I could have possibly done when trying to perform this?

Comment: "prevent duplicate email/usernames from being entered into the db" is not an application concern, it's a database schema concern, i.e. use constraints to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: Sorry about that. Maybe I should make better comments

Comment: Why are you binding a positional param `? ` like a named param `:s`?

Comment: @JorgeeFG That's the way it should be done.

Comment: @JorgeeFG Throughout all the examples I looked at, that was what they all included. I thought it was best since most examples said to do so.

Comment: @jack What am I missing? http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php why you say above is the way it should be done?

Comment: @JorgeeFG PDO !== mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for your particular problem here is by not using `COUNT(*)` as mentioned by John and not depend on `mysqli_stmt->num_rows` by using a buffered result set:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

return $stmt->execute() && $stmt->store_result() && $stmt->num_rows > 0;
```

#### Addendum

> The only thing I'm trying to do now is prevent duplicate email/usernames from being entered into the db

You will want to use table constraints to prevent this (not just from the app, but anything else that can access the database). This has the added benefit of guarding against race conditions.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE(email);
```

This will raise an error if you attempt to insert a row with an email value that already exists. You can check for this error on the application side and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I prefer doing things more robust. This is too simple and can generate too many errors.

Comment: @apotter96 This *is* the robust thing to do. Preventing duplicate emails should be done at an appropriate level.

Comment: If `email` should be unique in the table, then you *definitely should* add a unique constraint. Otherwise the application will be prone to race conditions. That said, a fix for the code in the question asked would allow for checking uniqueness without first attempting an `INSERT`.

Comment: I would recommend removing the ALTER TABLE Sql function since I did not use it. But all in all, the first bit of code works, it determines if the email already exists, and works properly fine. Thank you @Ja͢ck

Comment: @apotter96 The second part might still be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will *always* return 1 row. `COUNT(*)` will return a result set even if only to report no rows match your query. As a result `user_exists()` *always* returns `1`.

Change your query to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";
```

Now if no rows match your query `$stmt->num_rows` will be `0` so `user_exists()` will return `0`.

Comment: So, if I get the error `Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` does that mean the email is not already in the database?

Comment: That means your query failed because I gave you bad one. :/ See my update.

Comment: And yet, it still returns as if the email does not exist in the database, but it does

Comment: Echo out `$stmt->num_rows` and see if it is `0` or `1`. If it is `0` you  need to check your db and make sure it is *exactly* the same.

Comment: It is returning 0, sadly, but all the DB information matches up

Comment: What happens when you run the query in a tool like phpmyadmin?

Comment: It brings up where the email in the DB is just fine

Comment: Are you sure your code is looking at the right database?

Comment: It's my only Database. I have double and triple checked the db name. Matches perfectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80957/discussion-between-john-conde-and-apotter96).

Comment: Try hard coding the email address in the query

Comment: Still returns as if it isn't in the DB

Comment: Try making a simple example using simple old mysqli_query(). I'm kind of running out of ideas.

Comment: Yeah, this is insane. And it's going to end up being something simple and stupid too that no one would ever catch on to.

Comment: If you figure out let me know. The curiosity is killing me.

Comment: @JohnConde problem was caused by unbuffered query, so the num_rows didn't work as expected :)

Comment: Aaaahhhhhhh. I can sleep easier knowing that. Thanks for letting me know. It is *very* appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    return $stmt->num_rows;
}
What I then do is following:

if(user_exists($user_email) > 0) {
    echo "Email already exists!";
}
```

to

```
$j=0;
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $j= $stmt->num_rows;
} else {
    echo "Email already exists!";
}
```